# Bluetooth mouse wake up lag

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth

I bet this same question was asked a billion of times throughout the internet, however I was not able to find any workable solution for it.

So, the problem is in the wake-up lag on Bluetooth mouse. In other words, if mouse is left idle for like 3-5 seconds, it starts lagging for a couple of milliseconds as soon as I touch it. However it's not just *regular* lag, it's not like it doesn't respond at all for a second, it does respond, however the movement is not rendered correctly on the screen. I tried recording a short video, but not sure that shows correctly what the issue is. I started moving my mouse as soon as the video starts, however you should be able to see, that mouse almost *jumps* from the starting point to the right, and then starts moving smoothly by the end of the video.

[Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwEly.gif)

I tried basically everything I found on the internet, despite having Windows 10 20H2 (where some of the options are limited):

1. Updated\reinstalled every possible Bluetooth driver.
2. Disabled Bluetooth sleep in the Device manager - in my Windows version it is impossible to disable sleep directly on Bluetooth adapter, but I tried disabling it in HID-devices, GATT-Bluetooth and basically everywhere I found.
3. Tried disabling any kind of sleep in Power plans - yet again I have very limited options in this menu, however I was able to change USB and PCI-express settings through command line with powercfg.

This sums up my research and I will appreciate any additional thoughts on how to solve this issue.
It's extremely frustrating.

PS. One additional thing I noticed while typing this: click mouse button makes lag go away - if I start using my mouse by clicking any button it can be moved around flawlessly. Dunno if that makes any sense, at least it doesn't to me.

PPS. It is certainly not the mouse issue, since I'm using it for solid 5 years on multiple devices without any issues (Logitech MX Master)

PPPS. Lag is not constant - sometimes it doesn't lag, sometimes it lags for half-second, sometimes for more than a second.

Comment: If you have WiFi running, try Ethernet temporarily, instead. With a new routers, I've experienced WiFi vs. wireless mouse and keyboard conflicts.

Comment: Turning WiFi off didn't change a thing, unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What computer do you use? I've noticed that it's fine on my Surface Pro 4 but not my dell laptop

Comment: maybe you can try this: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Bluetooth-Mouse-Lag-Stutter-on-Lenovo-Yoga-7i-14/m-p/5060439?page=1 . It works well until I updated 2021.11.10 windows 10 21h1 patch. Now I'm crazy, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a low-end bluetooth mouse (Tecknet BM306).

Changing the single AA battery for fresh one solved the exact issues you described.