# Bluetooth Device Stalls / Hangs on Windows 11

Tags: windows, drivers, mouse, bluetooth, windows-11

I am using the [Surface Arc Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/surface-arc-mouse/8mrmszc6vxkc) from Microsoft on Windows 11 Home.

The mouse is made by Microsoft so I was hoping it would work well with Windows.

However, periodically there is a lot of lag / delay during input.

For example, when using the middle mouse "scroll wheel" or just moving the mouse around, *sometimes* there can be delay of 2-3 seconds.

This is not consistent and only seems to happen if I am not using the mouse for a few seconds, although it is hard to say for sure. Sometimes it also seems like this happens when I am using the mouse continuously.

I *believe* this also sometimes happens with my wired (USB) keyboard input (when I am typing characters and they do not show up for a second or two).

I do not know how isolate or debug this issue.

It seems like it could be a hardware issue, a bluetooth connection issue or some issue in the operating system.

Without any evidence my gut feeling is that the operating system has some sort of overun and can't handle input.

That is totally a guess.

The input is eventually received by Windows, nothing is ever "dropped" but the occasional pause is quite annoying (as usually I duplicate the gesture).

I updated my bluetooth driver to [this driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18649/intel-wireless-bluetooth-for-windows-10-and-windows-11.html?) I found online (device manager's update driver did not show an update) but it does not seem to help anything.

Does anybody know:

- How to fix the periodic input lags
- How to debug / locate what is causing the issue

I am particularly interested in any debugging tips that would also look at why keyboard input sometimes stalls too.

This happens with new batteries and battery percentage > 70%.

I do not see any options for "Bluetooth sleep" on Windows 11 in the device manager (and do not know what the difference between the "Bluetooth" section, and "mouse and pointer devices" section in input manager is).

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1607185/bluetooth-mouse-wake-up-lag

Comment: How new is the mouse? Have you contacted Microsoft Support.  40% of 1.5V is 0.6V and is insufficient for my LogiTech mice. I keep new batteries on hand.

Comment: For my mice, when the batteries drop to 1.2 or 1.1 volts (takes about 3 or 4 months), the behavior becomes erratic and I replace batteries.

Comment: Updated: It happens regardless of battery life.